# ReplaceAll replacing everything but what I specify

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I wish to replace all instances of a pipe in a specific string with something else. However, not only is it not replacing the specified string but instead replacing all blank spaces. Example:

```
String cleanTitle = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("Bacon is | good");
out.println(cleanTitle.replaceAll("|", "*"))
```

This example is outputting ***B*a*c*o*n*i*s*|*g*o*o*d***

I need it to say **Bacon is * good**

-The function escapeHTML is necessary for my interface, despite this example not using it for my question.

Comment: Writing Java code incorrectly inside a JSP file instead of a Java class and having problems with the particular Java code doesn't make it a JSP problem. You'd have had exactly the same problem when testing it in a normal Java class with a `main()` method. I have therefore removed the irrelevant `[jsp]` tag from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe in your expression, so use:

```
cleanTitle.replaceAll("\\|", "*")
```

See also

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: The important fact here is that replaceAll takes a regex (in opposite to replace).

Comment: The other sites I found examples for didn't say that it was a regex-specific function. My search results are terrible -__-

Answer (score 1):

The [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) does a regex matching and replacement. The `|` is a special character in regex and therefore needs to be escaped with `\` as answered by Jasper. However, you actually wanted a simple char-by-char search and replacement. The `String#replaceAll()` is the wrong tool for the purpose. You should be using [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) instead.

```
out.println(cleanTitle.replace('|', '*'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate suggestion. Would replace() have lower overhead than replaceAll() since it's not employing regex?